# pdo_mysql dsn when using composer

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose

So I created my docker-compose.yml file the following

```
web:
    build: ./config/apache
    volumes:
        - ./code:/var/www/html

db:
    build: ./config/db
    ports:
        - "3310:3310"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: testdatabase
        MYSQL_USER: test
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

I can see my phpinfo() when I add a index.php into my code directory, so its working fine.

Now I want to try to connect to my database with PDO

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=db;dbname=testdatabase;port=3310';
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

This gives me a

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I tried the host with

- db_1
- localhost

But nothing works, so what is the correct solution to connect to a dockerized database?

My config/db/Dockerfile is as simple as `FROM mysql:latest`

My config/apache/Dockerfile is

```
FROM php:7-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

Comment: Have you tried 127.0.0.1 for host ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: I might have found that mysql creates itself at port 3306 - [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306

Comment: That didnt change anything when im exposing port 3306 in my docker-compose instead

Comment: Restart your apache and try this : `mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=testdatabase`

Comment: I needed to link the db instance in my docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
web:
    build: ./config/apache
    volumes:
        - ./code:/var/www/html
    links:
        - db

db:
    build: ./config/db
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: testdatabase
        MYSQL_USER: test
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

Now I can use

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=db;dbname=testdatabase';
```

Where host is the name in the linked instance